# Why very magic flag can't take effect on character = in substitute command?

Tags: regular-expression, escape

We can see the explaination on `very magic` :With very magic, all ASCII characters except 0…9, a…z, A…Z and _ become a a special meaning. In this mode, searching for text becomes very magic.

When you write `()` as grouping character,no need to write as `\(\)` with `\v` in substitute command in vim.

The command `:%s/\v(.*)\=(.*)/"\1":"\2"/`  can convert belowing lines

```
pageFieldName1=Code
pageFieldValue1=
```

into

```
"pageFieldName1":"Code"
"pageFieldValue1":""
```

Why no need to escape for the characters `()` and `\=` is necessary in `s` command?
That is to say :

```
why?
:%s/\v(.*)\=(.*)/"\1":"\2"/  can work.
:%s/\v(.*)=(.*)/"\1":"\2"/   can not work.
```

Note :With very magic, all ASCII characters except 0…9, a…z, A…Z and _ become a special meaning.

Both `()` and `=` are not in the range mentioned here.

Updated ,add more content to discuss.

Let's convert the `=` into `-` in the lines,then both `=` and `-` are not in the range  `0…9, a…z, A…Z and _`.

```
pageFieldName1-Code
pageFieldValue1-
```

With same logic,

```
:%s/\v(.*)\=(.*)/"\1":"\2"/  can work.
:%s/\v(.*)=(.*)/"\1":"\2"/   can not work.
```

I can write

```
:%s/\v(.*)\-(.*)/"\1":"\2"/  can work.
:%s/\v(.*)-(.*)/"\1":"\2"/   can not work.
```

It is curious that `:%s/\v(.*)\-(.*)/"\1":"\2"/` and `:%s/\v(.*)-(.*)/"\1":"\2"/`  all can work,all of them convert the lines into:

```
"pageFieldName1":"Code"
"pageFieldValue1":""
```

Why?

Comment: Do you still have something open in the question? How can we help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

```
Use of "\v" means that after it, all ASCII characters except '0'-'9', 'a'-'z',
'A'-'Z' and '_' have special meaning
```

Where `special meaning` means the escaped version (e.g. `\(`) don't match the literal  (e.g. `(`) in normal mode.

Remark: It should have said: `have special meaning if any`

In the initial example both `(` and `=` have a special meaning.

The initial search was:

```
\(.*\)=\(.*\)
```

It is using:

- the special meaning of `(` and
- the ***non special*** meaning of `=`.

Because they are not in the range `0`-`9`, `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z` or `_` their meaning will be the special meaning if not escaped in very magic mode.

With very magic it translate into:

```
\v(.*)\=(.*)
```

Remark: The special meaning of `\=` is optional:

e.g.: `a\=b` match both `ab` or `b`.

Hence:

```
\v(.*)=(.*)
```

Search for an optional list of character followed by a list of character.

Then `\1` is the entire line and `\2` the empty string.

In the second example only `\(` has a special meaning.

The initial search is:

```
\(.*\)-\(.*\)
```

With very magic it translate into:

```
\v(.*)-(.*)
```

There is no need to escape `-` because `\-` has no special meaning.

The ranges `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z` or `_` play a role to exclude character that escaped have a special meaning.

E.g.: Although `\s` has a special meaning (i.e. in normal mode `\s` has not the same meaning as `s`) the very magic mode don't interpret `s` as its special meaning.

Hence:

```
\vs
```

is not equivalent to:

```
\s
```

Comment: Please have a look at my updated post.

Comment: The answer is in the first sentence `-` has no special meaning like `=` have. In normal pattern `\=` and `=` have not the same meaning but `-` and `\-` have the same meaning.

Comment: You say `In normal pattern \= and = have not the same meaning `,then what does `\=` and `=` mean respectively?

Comment: In normal pattern `=` match `=` literally like `-` match `-`. But `\=` is equivalent to `?` in Python or Perl pattern. e.g.: `a\=b` match `ab` or `b`.